# Proof on set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got this equality $(A \times B) = (A\cup B) \times(A\cup B)$. I've already shown the left-to-right inclusion, and I want to refute the other way by giving a counterexample. I want to show that given an ordered pair $(x,y) \in (A\cup B) \times(A\cup B)$, $(x,y)$ does not always belong to $(A \times B)$, thus giving the needed counterexample.

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-zero sets. And let $B$ be a proper subset of $A$, then, there must be at least an element $a \in A$ that is not an element of $B$, $a \notin B$. So, for every ordered pair $(x,y) \in (A\cup B) \times (A\cup B)$, we got that $x \in (A\cup B)$ and also $y\in (A \cup B)$.

If the equality was right, for all $x \in (A\cup B)$, $x \in A$. And for all $y \in (A\cup B)$, $y \in B$. We got that $(A \cup B) = A$, therefore, the following statements are equivalent:

$(1) \quad x \in A$

$(2) \quad x \in (A \cup B)$

But, by definition of $A$ and $B$, and knowing that $(A \cup B) = A$, we come to $B \subset A$, hence, the following statement is NOT TRUE:

$(1)\quad y \in (A \cup B) \rightarrow y \in B$,

because we can find at least one element that belongs to $(A \cup B)$ but not to $B$. Q.E.D.

I want to know if this proof is formally correct, and if there is any mistake.

Comment: If all you want to do is a counterexample, the following would be simpler: Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$, Then $A\times B = \{(a,b)\} \ne \{(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\} = (A\cup B)\times(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Note that if you want to prove that two sets are not the same then there is completely no need to prove that one is a subset of the other. However, if you goal is to find out as much as you can about how they are related then by all means do so.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $ A\neq B $. This means that either $ A\nsubseteq B $ or $ B\nsubseteq A $. Wlog, suppose $ B\nsubseteq A $, so there is $ x\in B\setminus A$. Then $ x\in A\cup B $ and thus $(x, x)\in (A\cup B)\times (A\cup B) $, but $(x, x)\notin A\times B $ because $ x\notin A $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when you are looking for a counter-example for a problem, look at specific examples. Here you can take $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$. Then (if you need to) use your specific counter-example as a starting point for finding a more general class of counter-examples.